# How to catch standard errors from expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

the following expect script will remove the file /var/tmp/file on remote machine

but before that the expect script do ssh on the remote machine ,

I put the `2>/tmp/errors` in order to catch error from ssh

but I notice that in spite ssh to remote send error , I not see the errors from `/tmp/errors` file

but when I tryed manual the

```
ssh   $LOGIN@$machine
```

then ssh fail on  `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED`

but from the expect I cant to catch this errors in `/tmp/erros`

please advice what’s is wrong ? why `2>/tmp/errors` not capture the errors?

```
 expect_test=`cat << EOF
 set timeout 50
 spawn  ssh   $LOGIN@$machine  2>/tmp/errors
       expect {
                 ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

                 word:  { sleep 1 ; send $PASSORD\r}
              }
 expect >  {send "sleep 1\r"}
 expect >  {send "rm -f /var/tmp/file\r"}
 expect >    {send exit\r}
 expect eof
 EOF` 


 expect -c  "$expect_remove_file"
```

Comment: hi Etan how are you - thx for the update

Comment: I don't know, offhand, if you can use redirections in `spawn` commands like that. If you can you probably, at very least, need to quote it for tcl. That being said if expect isn't reading standard error (and I don't recall offhand if it does) you can probably stick that on the `expect -c` execution directly to get what you want.

Comment: duplicated on superuser: http://superuser.com/q/835794/4714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spawn` does not understand I/O redirection. Replace

```
spawn  ssh   $LOGIN@$machine  2>/tmp/errors
```

with either

```
spawn  ssh   $LOGIN@$machine -E /tmp/errors
# -E log_file tells ssh where to write the error log instead of stderr
```

or

```
spawn  sh -c "ssh $LOGIN@$machine 2>/tmp/errors"
```